# Search based on matching keywords with Algolia

Tags: algolia

Is it possible to perform a query and return result based on matching queries? Please see my example below.

**Example objects:**

- ID="1" product="car"
- ID="2" product="racing car"
- ID="3" product="electric racing car"

**Example search:** 
racing car

Returns the following objects in order: 2, 3, 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consider all words as optional with Algolia, you can pass an array composed of all the words of the query in your request:

```
index.search('racing car', {
  optionalWords: ['racing', 'car']
});
```

This will give you the results in the order you expect.

Algolia provides another related option, [`removeWordsIfNoResults`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-removeWordsIfNoResults), which will consider some words as optional if and only if it doesn't find results matching every word of the query.